# Oracle SQL Developer - Driver Class not found. Vendor code 0 with xampp

Tags: oracle, xampp, oracle-sqldeveloper

was looking for some help. For some reason this morning when opening SQL Developer and clicking on my connection I get the following error message:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

Drive class not found.
Verify the Driver location

Vendor code 0
```

Not sure what has happened but all was working last night. I tried to access the database on phpmyadmin in xampp and thats just loading. Honestly don't understand whats gone wrong. I have seen posts about updating the JDBC driver in Preferences but I didn't have this from the start so not sure why I need to add this now.

Comment: an Oracle connection?

Comment: MySQL connection

Comment: make sure it's listed correctly in the 3rd party jdbc driver page in preferences

Comment: Thanks jeff, just added the location of the jdbc driver and its started working.

Comment: if you search SO, this question is already asked/answered

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it was more a case that it was working a few hours ago without the change in the JDBC Driver location hence wanted to see what might have caused the issue all of a sudden.